# java game timer using a lot of resources

Tags: java, timer, cpu

So im making a game in java, and i have a problem. The timer uses a lot of cpu resources(around 30%) and it probably shouldnt. When i try to put render in the tick timer, everything works fine. And sometimes, without changing anything it works fine

```
public static synchronized void run(){
    long last = System.nanoTime();
    double npt = Time.nano / tps; //one second / ticks
    double delta = 0;
    //long now;

    long pfmLast = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long pfmSpm = Time.nano * spu;
    long pfmDelta = 0;
    int pfmUpdates = 0;
    long pfmNow;

    long fpsLast = System.nanoTime();
    double npf = Time.nano / fps; //one second / ticks
    double fpsDelta = 0;
    //long fpsNow;

    int frames = 0;

    Handler.init();


    try {
        en = new Entity(ImageIO.read(new File("res/robot.png")), 1, 1, false);
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    while(running){
        long now = System.nanoTime();
        delta += (now - last)/npt;
        last = now;

        while(delta >= 1){
            pfmUpdates++;
            Handler.update();

            delta -= 1;
        }

        long fpsNow = System.nanoTime();
        fpsDelta += (fpsNow - fpsLast)/npf;
        fpsLast = fpsNow;



        while(fpsDelta >= 1){
            frames++;
            render();
            Handler.render();

            fpsDelta -= 1;
        }



        if(loggingPerformance){
            pfmNow = System.currentTimeMillis();
            pfmDelta += pfmNow-pfmLast;
            pfmLast = pfmNow;

            if(pfmDelta >= 1000){
                System.out.println(pfmUpdates + ", " + frames);
                frames = 0;
                pfmUpdates = 0;
                pfmDelta=0;
            }

        }




        try {
            Thread.sleep(2);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        /*fpsNow = System.currentTimeMillis();
        fpsDelta += fpsNow - fpsLast;
        fpsLast = fpsNow;

        if(fpsDelta >= npf){
            //Handler.render();

            frames++;
            fpsDelta -= npf;
        }*/


    }
}
```

Comment: What kind of game is it? What GUI library? Those while loops worry me as they'll burn cpu cycles.

Comment: Have you tried profiling your app?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels its not using any liberarys, and for now its only drawing entities on an image which is being drawn to an canvas

Comment: Thread.sleep(2) essentially does nothing.  You are not rendering at any particular frame rate;  you are rendering as frequently as the computer allows.  I’m not surprised the CPU is strained.

Comment: Hint: read about **single layer of abstraction** principle. Your one poor method is also using a lot of **statements** of various levels that would better go into quite several helper methods to make that code more readable.

Comment: `"its not using any liberarys"` -- that doesn't make sense and suggests that you don't fully understand what a GUI library is. It has to use some library to allow graphics to be translated to the native platform. This can be Swing (e.g., JFrame) or AWT (e.g., Applet) or Android, but you have to be using **some** gui library.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels its using swing

Comment: And hint: you want us to spend our time to help you. So you might consider to spent the 1 minute it takes to properly format/indent your code to make that easier for us; for example by removing all those wasted empty lines in there ...

Comment: Then use a Swing Timer for your game loop.

Comment: The thread's sleep time should be determined (each frame) based on the desired framerate and the time needed to render and update. i.e. `sleepTimeMilliSec = (targetFrameTimeNanos - measuredRenderUpdateTimeNanos)/1000000;`

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you have several while loops which are basically calculating the state of your game for each nanosecond in `delta`.

This puts an enormous strain on your computer.

What you should do instead is make whatever calculation you do in `Handler.render()` a function of `delta` so you only have to calculate it once instead of `1.000.000.000` times for each second passed!

So I'm thinking that this

```
    while(delta >= 1){
        pfmUpdates++;
        Handler.update();

        delta -= 1;
    }
```

should become something like this:

```
    Handler.update(delta)
```